# Get Third Party URL from wordpress media library. Image come from Third Party URL. Please provide its wordpress hook

Tags: wordpress, media

I have some product image urls. Images is from third party urls. I want to import these images and show images in media but url not coming in wordpress directory. Image will come from third party url and just show in media library.

I have tried some wordpress hooks but image stored in folder I want to show just image show in library and getting image url from third party. I have used some media upload hooks but these are not working

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';

function upload_image_from_url($image_url) {
    // Check if the URL is valid
    if (filter_var($image_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        // Get the file type
        $file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($image_url), null);

        // Prepare an array of data for the attachment
        $attachment = array(
            'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name(basename($image_url)),
            'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
        );

        // Try to upload the image
        $attachment_id = media_sideload_image($image_url, 0, null, 'id');

        if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
            // The image was successfully uploaded, and $attachment_id contains the attachment ID.
            return $attachment_id;
        } else {
            // An error occurred during the upload.
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Example usage:
$image_url = 'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/727/536/354.jpg?hmac=FPxn7oYjZgvXjjpn7dUunkQgtA6hwYZ4HcnchtahC2g';
$attachment_id = upload_image_from_url($image_url);

if ($attachment_id) {
    // The image was uploaded successfully. You can use $attachment_id as needed.
} else {
    // There was an error uploading the image.
}
```

Comment: But this image is storing in media. We don't want to store this. We want to directly fetch from URL and show in media library thats it.